# How to handle escape characters using JAXB marshaller

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, escaping, marshalling

I am using JAXB Marshaller and I want to escape characters. For example double quotes `"` is showing as �.

How to handle these?

I am setting the properties by following other similar posts but didn't solved the issue.

**Code:**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass().getPackage().getName());         
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
    @Override
     public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, Writer out) throws IOException {
            out.write( ch, start, length ); 
     }     
});
marshaller.marshal(object, stringWriter);
```

Answer (score 2):

The marshaller should be able to use encoding

```
marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i have changed that. But still can see these characters "�" and "?" in place of quotes and other escpainf charcaters. any suggestions? Also the XML is defined with : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: I don't see these characters.

Comment: I mean i can see them in the output @RomanC. The characters appear differently :(

Comment: I didn't get what you saying.

Comment: i have the marshall property to : marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "UTF-8"); but still after that i can see a double quote is displayed as ? and i can see some weird symbols Example: used�by�people from engineers to home inventors to�make

Comment: The encoding is set to the marshaller UTF-8 it should support double quote displaying.

Comment: How to make it to do support double quote displaying. can you please suggest? @RomanC

Comment: Where do you want to display?